# Synchronize the Playing of Multiple Video Files in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, video, netstream

I would like to have one controller to sync and control multiple video objects(start/stop simultaneously). Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand your question.  If I do, the answer is yes.

You can have one class as act as the controller for several videos (FLVPlaybacks, JW Player, FlowPlayer)...

Essentially you would use your 1 controller to proxy any calls you would make so a single video to all of your videos.   So you would have something like the following:

```
function play():void {
    for (var i:Number = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        videos[i].play();
    }
}
```

or even

```
function play():void {
    var playVideo:Function = function() { this.play() };
    map(playVideo, vides);
}
```

Comment: I just started working in as3 again after a while away and that map method is fantastic. Thanks!

I just had trouble implementing it. This finally worked:
 public function playAll():void {
     var playVideo:Function = function(item:NetStream, index:int, vctr:Vector.<NetStream>):void { item.resume() };
    myStreams.map(playVideo);
  }